# In SQL how do I get the maximum value for an integer?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to find out the maximum value for an integer (signed or unsigned) from a MySQL database. Is there a way to pull back this information from the database itself?

Are there any built-in constants or functions I can use (either standard SQL or MySQL specific).

At http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html it lists the values - but is there a way for the database to tell me.

The following gives me the MAX_BIGINT - what I'd like is the MAX_INT.

```
SELECT CAST( 99999999999999999999999 AS SIGNED ) as max_int;
# max_int | 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Rewrite it from a table (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html). This not change any way, you can define it const.

Comment: Be aware that you will have different values for SIGNED v. UNSIGNED ints.

Comment: Hi CoffeeMonster. Did you check out my answer? If you consider it the right one, please check it as such. Much appreciated, 

Roland.

Comment: CoffeeMonster, I have updated my answer. Please take a look and see what you think. TIA, Roland

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In Mysql there is a cheap trick to do this:

```
mysql> select ~0;
+----------------------+
| ~0                   |
+----------------------+
| 18446744073709551615 |
+----------------------+
```

the tilde is the bitwise negation. The resulting value is a bigint. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-invert

For the other integer flavours, you can use the right bitshift operator `>>` like so:

```
SELECT ~0 as max_bigint_unsigned
,      ~0 >> 32 as max_int_unsigned
,      ~0 >> 40 as max_mediumint_unsigned
,      ~0 >> 48 as max_smallint_unsigned
,      ~0 >> 56 as max_tinyint_unsigned
,      ~0 >> 1  as max_bigint_signed
,      ~0 >> 33 as max_int_signed
,      ~0 >> 41 as max_mediumint_signed
,      ~0 >> 49 as max_smallint_signed
,      ~0 >> 57 as max_tinyint_signed
\G

*************************** 1. row ***************************
   max_bigint_unsigned: 18446744073709551615
      max_int_unsigned: 4294967295
max_mediumint_unsigned: 16777215
 max_smallint_unsigned: 65535
  max_tinyint_unsigned: 255
     max_bigint_signed: 9223372036854775807
        max_int_signed: 2147483647
  max_mediumint_signed: 8388607
   max_smallint_signed: 32767
    max_tinyint_signed: 127
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is a much nicer way to workout the max(Big_Int). 
What I'm after is max(Signed) and max(Unsigned).

Comment: What will happen if MySql decides to add in new version, lets say, HYPERINT (16 bytes)? Will this break finding mediumint, tinyint, smallint? While I understand you can find the biggest int value by ~0 then I think looking for smallint, mediumint, tinyint by bit shifting from maximum value is not so wise.

Comment: Kamil, while you're technically right, I started my answer by stating it was a "cheap trick". IOW, it solves the problem posed by the initial question, but does not pretend to be anything more. However, you shouldn't feel held back to post your solution to the problem.

Comment: A better way to do it would be to use masks, `SELECT ~0 & 0xFFFFFFFF` for unsigned int. This way it's not dependent upon the size of `~0`.

Comment: @CoffeeMonster Can you give supported Mysql version number for your solution? I tried at Mysql 5.7, it's giving syntax error. By the way I have chosen original solution.  (bitwise trick) It's enough for most cases. Thanks.

Comment: The ~0 shorthand is clever for a big value, but does this solution miss the point? If you're hard-coding the number of _bits_ for each type, why not simply hard-code the _value_ for each type? The usual reason to use system-wide constants (if they exist) is so that they would allow you to automatically follow structural changes to MySQL itself.

Comment: "The ~0 shorthand is clever for a big value, but does this solution miss the point?" < No - it is exactly the right solution for the original question.

For the other values, you might have a point, but the advantage of the bitshift solution is that it is more compact and leaves less room for typos. But the drawback is that it is a tad cryptic.

Comment: this is an absolutely fantastic hack

Answer (score -2):

There does not seem to be any built-in constants to supply these values.  Since most likely they will not change, you should be safe either hard-coding them or setting their values to a lookup table or variable.