# Easy way to compute how close an auto_increment is to its maximum value?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

So yesterday we had a table that has an auto_increment PK for a smallint that reached its maximum.  We had to alter the table on an emergency basis, which is definitely not how we like to roll.

Is there an easy way to report on how close each auto_increment field that we use is to its maximum?  The best way I can think of is to do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement, parse out the size of the auto-incremented column, then compare that to the AUTO_INCREMENT value for the table.

On the other hand, given that the schema doesn't change very often, should I store information about the columns' maximum values and get the current AUTO_INCREMENT with `SHOW TABLE STATUS`?

Comment: why do you have the database set up with small ints? do you re use deleted PKs from your table that have been removed? and how is the data integrity maintained if the pk field is removed? I only ask because would it more beneficial to remake a new database allowing for more memory to be allocated to it or do you only store data temporarily and then remove it when it no longer serves, like a temporary storage.

Comment: It's an old data model that was created when people cared about disk space more than they do now.  The data model isn't as malleable as I might like.

Comment: what's wrong with the data model? alter table query isn't allowed? or what?

Comment: I've noticed most people here never make auto-inc columns "unsigned" - a negative ID value to me is silly... I always have unsigned ID columns, and effectively double my id space. I also make them bigints, since disk space is cheap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question seems perfectly reasonable to me. You should be able to get the current auto-increment values for each table from information_schema. I don't think the max values for the various int types are available as constants in MySQL, but Roland Bouman demonstrated a simple way to generate them in MySQL:

[In SQL how do I get the maximum value for an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679064/in-sql-how-do-i-get-the-maximum-value-for-an-integer/2679152)

If you put that data into a table, then you can write a single SQL query to get the current auto-increment status of all of your tables so you can see how close you are to running out of values.

Here's a quick-and-dirty example to get you started:

```
create temporary table max_int_values
(
int_type varchar(10) not null,
extra varchar(8) not null default '',
max_value bigint unsigned not null,
primary key (int_type,max_value),
key int_type (int_type),
key max_value (max_value)
);

insert into max_int_values(int_type,extra,max_value) values ('tinyint','',~0 >> 57);
insert into max_int_values(int_type,extra,max_value) values ('tinyint','unsigned',~0 >> 56);
insert into max_int_values(int_type,extra,max_value) values ('smallint','',~0 >> 49);
insert into max_int_values(int_type,extra,max_value) values ('smallint','unsigned',~0 >> 48);
insert into max_int_values(int_type,extra,max_value) values ('mediumint','',~0 >> 41);
insert into max_int_values(int_type,extra,max_value) values ('mediumint','unsigned',~0 >> 40);
insert into max_int_values(int_type,extra,max_value) values ('int','',~0 >> 33);
insert into max_int_values(int_type,extra,max_value) values ('int','unsigned',~0 >> 32);
insert into max_int_values(int_type,extra,max_value) values ('bigint','',~0 >> 1);
insert into max_int_values(int_type,extra,max_value) values ('bigint','unsigned',~0);

select t.table_Schema,t.table_name,c.column_name,c.column_type,
  t.auto_increment,m.max_value,
  round((t.auto_increment/m.max_value)*100,2) as pct_of_values_used,
  m.max_value - t.auto_increment as values_left
from information_schema.tables t
  inner join information_schema.columns c 
    on c.table_Schema = t.table_Schema and c.table_name = t.table_name
  inner join max_int_values m 
    on m.int_type = substr(c.column_type,1,length(m.int_type)) 
    and ((m.extra like '%unsigned') = (c.column_type like '%unsigned'))
where c.extra = 'auto_increment'
order by pct_of_values_used;
```

Comment: This is overkill for my particular needs, but it looks like a good general solution.

Comment: @David: Why do you think this is overkill? I think this is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: It's overkill "for my particular needs." For the general case, this is indeed exactly what I asked for.

Answer (score 9):

[From openark](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/checking-for-auto_increment-capacity-with-single-query), here is a single query for checking auto-increment capacity:

```
SELECT
  TABLE_SCHEMA,
  TABLE_NAME,
  COLUMN_NAME,
  DATA_TYPE,
  COLUMN_TYPE,
  IF(
    LOCATE('unsigned', COLUMN_TYPE) > 0,
    1,
    0
  ) AS IS_UNSIGNED,
  (
    CASE DATA_TYPE
      WHEN 'tinyint' THEN 255
      WHEN 'smallint' THEN 65535
      WHEN 'mediumint' THEN 16777215
      WHEN 'int' THEN 4294967295
      WHEN 'bigint' THEN 18446744073709551615
    END >> IF(LOCATE('unsigned', COLUMN_TYPE) > 0, 0, 1)
  ) AS MAX_VALUE,
  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  AUTO_INCREMENT / (
    CASE DATA_TYPE
      WHEN 'tinyint' THEN 255
      WHEN 'smallint' THEN 65535
      WHEN 'mediumint' THEN 16777215
      WHEN 'int' THEN 4294967295
      WHEN 'bigint' THEN 18446744073709551615
    END >> IF(LOCATE('unsigned', COLUMN_TYPE) > 0, 0, 1)
  ) AS AUTO_INCREMENT_RATIO
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES USING (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME)
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('mysql', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA', 'performance_schema')
  AND EXTRA='auto_increment'
;
```

And of course you can add an `ORDER BY AUTO_INCREMENT_RATIO DESC` with perhaps a `LIMIT` to easily pick out the ones closest to their limit.

Answer (score 0):

just make it int unsigned and forget about it's value forever.

Comment: See my comment above about why we're averse to data model changes.

Comment: `INT UNSIGNED` is only 32 bits. That isn't *forever* (experience speaks).

Answer (score 0):

One solution I was able to find was using a an advisor.

[LINK](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/advisors.html)

the advisor monitors your database for any changes to the schema, memory usage, performance, etc.

but it also allows you to `Build custom Rules tailored to the needs of your particular MySQL environment`. In essence you could create a your own monitoring advisor, which I have noticed someone doing, however did not explain how. therefor you could send a warning when you limit is about to be reached.

and a solution to reaching the limit could be to create another column with a second ID, making the PK become a composite primary key effectively extending the amount of id's you have without having to change the data type.

ex:

add second PK ID field called 'Whatever'

lets say your limit is 1024 rows to be added under auto increment, your second column auto increment after the first one has reached it's limit, resetting the first one to 1 and having the second jump to 2

```
1023 1
1024 1
1    2
2    2
etc.
```

there would need to be references made in the other tables but doesn't require you to mess with the data type. this is by far not the best solution to the problem, and you might have thought of something better already, but I figure I might add it just in case it makes you think of another solution.

either way, however you decide to fix/monitor the limit being reached another database should be planned out and created. a monitor or a another field or however you managed to fix the database in a hurry is only a band aid on the real problem at hand, because if you have other fields like that, with small limits, then you don't want to be stuck the day that more then one field decides to reach it's limit at the same time.

hope this helps somewhat.