# How to find least non-null column in one particular row in SQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to find the lowest number in two columns of a row in the same table, with the caveat that one of the columns may be null in a particular row. If one of the columns is null, I want the value in the other column returned for that row, as that is the lowest non-null column in this case. If I use the least() function in MySQL 5.1:

```
select least(1,null)
```

This returns null, which is not what I want. I need the query to return 1 in this case.

I've been able to get the result I want in general with this query:

```
select least(coalesce(col1, col2)) , coalesce(col2,col1))
```

As long as col1 and col2 are both not null each coalesce statement will return a number, and the least() handles finding the lowest.

Is there a simpler/faster way to do this? I'm using MySQL in this instance but general solutions are welcomed.

Comment: faster? Have you determined it to be slow?

Comment: Haven't judged it to be slow necessarily, but it's calling 3 functions instead of possibly one. I'm using it in an order by clause of a query I need to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Unfortunately (for your case) behaviour of LEAST was changed in MySQL 5.0.13 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) - it used to return NULL only if all arguments are NULL.

This change was even reported as a bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=15610
But the fix was only to MySQL documentation, explaining new behaviour and compatibility break.

Your solution was one of the recommended workarounds. Another can be using IF operator:

```
SELECT IF(Col1 IS NULL OR Col2 IS NULL, COALESCE(Col1, Col2), LEAST(Col1,Col2))
```

Comment: Great info but the workaround only works with 2 values, if you add a `Col3` it's not working anymore. In that case this is the workaround: `LEAST(COALESCE(a,b,c), COALESCE(b,c,a), COALESCE(c,a,b))` which will get very messy with for example 10 columns. Let's hope a `NLEAST()` function will be added one day...

Answer (score 10):

This is how I solved it:

```
select coalesce(least(col1, col2), col1, col2)
```

If one value is NULL, the query will return the first non-NULL value. You can even add a default value as the last parameter, if both values can be NULL.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your corner case situation of having all values be `null`, I would go for such syntax, which is more readable (An easier solution if you have exactly two columns is below!)

```sql
SELECT LEAST( IFNULL(5, ~0 >> 1), IFNULL(10, ~0 >> 1) ) AS least_date;
-- Returns: 5

SELECT LEAST( IFNULL(null, ~0 >> 1), IFNULL(10, ~0 >> 1) ) AS least_date;
-- Returns: 10

SELECT LEAST( IFNULL(5, ~0 >> 1), IFNULL(null, ~0 >> 1) ) AS least_date;
-- Returns: 5

SELECT LEAST( IFNULL(null, ~0 >> 1), IFNULL(null, ~0 >> 1)) AS least_date
-- Returns: @MAX_VALUE (If you need to use it as default value)

SET @MAX_VALUE=~0 >> 1;
SELECT LEAST( IFNULL(null, @MAX_VALUE), IFNULL(null, @MAX_VALUE)) AS least_date;
-- Returns: @MAX_VALUE (If you need to use it as default value). Variables just makes it more readable!

SET @MAX_VALUE=~0 >> 1;
SELECT NULLIF(
    LEAST( IFNULL(null, @MAX_VALUE), IFNULL(null,@MAX_VALUE)),
    @MAX_VALUE
) AS least_date;
-- Returns: NULL
```

That is my prefered way if

- you can ensure that at least one column cannot be `NULL`
- in corner case situation (all columns are `NULL`) you want a non-null default value which greater than any possible value or can get limited to a certain threshold
- You can deal with variables to make this statement even more readable

If you question yourself what `~0 >> 1` means:
It's just a short hand for saying "Give me the greatest number available". See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2679152/2427579

**Even better, if you have only two columns**, you can use:

```
SELECT LEAST( IFNULL(@column1, @column2), IFNULL(@column2, @column1) ) AS least_date;
-- Returns: NULL (if both columns are null) or the least value
```

Answer (score 3):

This may perform a bit better (may have to be converted to corresponding MySql syntax):

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN Col1 IS NULL THEN Col2
    WHEN Col2 IS NULL THEN Col1
    ELSE Least(Col1, Col2)
  END
```

Another alternative (probably slower though, but worth a try):

```
SELECT Col1
WHERE Col2 IS NULL
UNION
SELECT Col2
WHERE Col1 IS NULL
UNION
SELECT least(Col1, Col2)
WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col2 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not set the value of one column to be equal to the other column when it's NULL?

```
SELECT LEAST(IFNULL(COL1, COL2), IFNULL(COL2, COL1));
```

with the code above, the null value will be ignored unless both are null.

e.g.

COL1 = NULL, COL2 = 5

```
LEAST(IFNULL(NULL, 5), IFNULL(5, NULL)) -> LEAST(5, 5) -> 5
```

COL1 = 3, COL2 = NULL

```
LEAST(IFNULL(3, NULL), IFNULL(NULL, 3)) -> LEAST(3, 3) -> 3
```

COL1 = NULL, COL2 = NULL

```
LEAST(IFNULL(NULL, NULL), IFNULL(NULL, NULL)) -> LEAST(NULL, NULL) -> NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 
MIN(LEAST(COALESCE(COL1, COL2), COALESCE(COL2,CO1)))
WHERE COL1 IS NOT NULL
    AND COL2 IS NOT NULL;

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function which handles any number of dates, by concatenating them with a separator (CONCAT_WS) as first parameter to the function.

`CONCAT_WS` besides dynamic number of parameters, will remove all NULL dates ;)

The function accepts two parameters:

- delimiter separated string of dates as TEXT
- delimiter as TEXT (same as used on CONCAT_WS !!) - you can remove it if you use only preferred separator on CONCAT_WS.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION `min_date`(`dates` TEXT, `delim` VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS DATE NO SQL DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE `result` DATE DEFAULT NULL;

DECLARE `count` TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE `temp` DATE DEFAULT NULL;

IF `delim` IS NULL THEN SET `delim` = ','; END IF;

IF `dates` IS NOT NULL AND CHAR_LENGTH(`dates`) > 0 THEN 
  SET `count` = LENGTH(`dates`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`dates`, `delim`, SPACE(CHAR_LENGTH(`delim`) - 1)));

  WHILE `count` >= 0 DO
    SET `temp` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`dates`, `delim`, `count` + 1), `delim`, -1);

    IF `result` IS NULL OR `result` > `temp` THEN SET `result` = `temp`; END IF;

    SET `count` = `count` - 1;
  END WHILE;
END IF;

RETURN `result`;

END
```

Then, you can use in any combination of date fields or as static strings (as long as are valid dates or NULL):

```sql
SELECT min_date(CONCAT_WS(',', `date_column_1`, NULL, '2019-03-04', `date_column_2`), ',') AS `min_date`
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple (yet not beautiful) solution is the following.

If you're looking for the smallest non-null value, you can use IFNULL with the second parameter beingthe 'INT limit'

```
ORDER BY LEAST(
    IFNULL(properties.sale_value, 2147483647),
    IFNULL(properties.rental_value, 2147483647),
    IFNULL(properties.daily_rental_value, 2147483647)
) ASC
```

And if you're looking for the biggest non-null value, you can use IFNULL with the second parameter being 1, ( or the first negative value below your limit, if you don't know it, use the negative int limit )

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(
    IFNULL(properties.sale_value, 1),
    IFNULL(properties.rental_value, 1),
    IFNULL(properties.daily_rental_value, 1)
) ASC
```