# MySQL query selecting the least non-null, non-zero integer

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has 5 columns: `uniqueid`, `int1`, `int2`, `int3`, and `FruitStand`. What I'm looking for is an example on how to do a single select that outputs the data of whichever column has the least non-null, non-zero integer.

Example Table:

```
uniqueid|int1|int2|int3|FruitStand
1       |   2|   3|   4|Apples
2       |  21|   4|   0|Oranges
3       |NULL|   2|   5|Pears
```

So I would get the results from this query of

```
1       |   2|Apples
2       |   4|Oranges
3       |   2|Pears
```

Comment: if it's "whichever column is not null and the value is not 0" then why the expected result omits 21 from the second record? it's somewhat confusing. can you maybe spell out more of your assumptions?

Comment: @PavelVeller excluding if the column is not null and the value is not 0.   Does that help?  I put it in the edit

Comment: makes sense. I guess I didn't see the `least` part of the rule.

Comment: There is another way using `IFNULL` withing `LEAST()`. Please see:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36601711/2427579

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT uniqueid,
FruitStand,
LEAST(
    COALESCE(int1, int2, int3),
    COALESCE(int2, int3, int1),
    COALESCE(int3, int1, int2)) AS number
FROM myTable
```

For readability, I omitted the `NULLIF(intX, 0)` for each argument in `COALESCE`. You will need to add those to ignore zero values.

You will need to use `COALESCE` to avoid `NULL` values when using the `LEAST` function because as of MySQL 5.0.13, `LEAST` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078370/how-to-find-least-non-null-column-in-one-particular-row-in-sql) for details on that.

Comment: Evan, Are you sure about the nullif?  I tried without the nullif and the it repeats the lowest regardless of the null

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT LEAST(
    IF(int1,int1,999999),
    IF(int2,int2,999999),
    IF(int3,int3,999999)
);
```

Here, the value 999999 should be the maximum possible value for those columns.

Comment: `IFNULL(int1, 999999)` is shorter