# Fill column to max value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know if its possible to automatically fill a column to its max value if the value inside it isn't already at the max value. For example, if I have a column called score that takes an INT(11) and the data in that column is just 23, is there a way I can get it to add a bunch of numbers to the end of it so its size is actually 11 and not 2? so in the end it would look something like 23000000000?

Comment: You're not making much sense on the goal of what you want to achieve but you can get the max value automatically see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2679152/342740

Comment: @Prix sorry this is pretty difficult for me to explain. Let me try another example. If I have a column that takes VARCHAR(20) and the data in that column is "person name". that there is VARCHAR(11) in total. Could I possible get it to add like another 39 characters such as a blank space to make the total size of it 50?

Comment: Why do you want to make that? It would make your DB huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask about is called `padding`. You *could* do that at the database schema level, using a varchar column, but I suggest against it for several reason, including no auto-increment numbers. You can easily pad the number as you like while you query the database, for instance using:

```
SELECT LPAD('columnname',11,'0')
```

Comment: yes thank you that is exactly what I was looking for. Just one for thing. What is the syntax to detect if a column is not at its max size? so then possibly LPAD could automatically fill it to the required amount

Comment: The size of integer columns is a non-standard extension of sql in mysql: it does not have any effect on column size and it is used only for display purposes.

Comment: Anyway if you want to get that piece of metainfo, you can try to parse the output of the *show columns from _tablename_* or *show create table _tablename_* commands