# What's a better way of saying `col1 < IFNULL(col2, 999999)` and `ORDER BY IFNULL(col3, 999999)`?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I were in a procedural programming language I'd use something like sys.MAX_INT in place of 999999. Does such a thing exist in SQL? Or is there a neater way to get rid of the 999999 in this SQL?

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
    tbl1 
WHERE 
    col1 < IFNULL(col2, 999999) 
ORDER BY 
    IFNULL(col3, 999999);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
select t.*
from tb1 t
where col1 < col2 or col2 is null
order by (col3 is not null) desc, col3;
```

Comment: Is there an efficiency gain over using `is null` over `IFNULL()`?

Comment: Or `ORDER BY -col3 DESC`

Comment: `col3 is null` is equivalent to `(col3 is not null) desc`

Comment: @SterlingArcher I'd assume there would be since IFNULL() provides for a "branching" of sorts on an implied condition, whereas IS NULL is just a condition. IFNULL implicitly performs an IS NULL check, and then decides whether to return a different value.  However, now that you mention it, while IS NULL is almost certainly faster than IFNULL(); I can't be positive if the sorting on two dimensions instead of one negates any efficiency gains.

Comment: @SterlingArcher . . . The difference is negligible because an index would not be used for this query.  The most important difference is that `is null` is ANSI standard syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `~0` instead of "MAX_INT"

Please check this answer.

[In SQL how do I get the maximum value for an integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679064/in-sql-how-do-i-get-the-maximum-value-for-an-integer#answer-2679152)

In your case...

```
SELECT 
     * 
FROM 
    tbl1 
WHERE 
    col1 < IFNULL(col2, ~0) 
ORDER BY 
    IFNULL(col3, ~0);
```

Comment: Not if the value is signed.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Why?

Comment: @shmosel . . . I think ~0 is a negative number.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I don't think so. AFAIK, all bitwise operations return UNSIGNED BIGINT.